# Can't manage to get gl3w working with atom

Tags: c++, opengl

So the problem is that when I've compiled gl3w.h and inserted it into my MinGW/include/GL I'm getting such error:

```
In file included from B:\REPO\game\main.cpp:2:0: 
b:\mingw\include\gl\gl3w.h:84:3: error: 'PFNGLBINDTEXTUREPROC' does not name a type 
PFNGLBINDTEXTUREPROC BindTexture;
```

The code I'm trying to run is:

```
        #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <GL/gl3w.h>
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      glfwInit();

      GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640,480, "Triangles", NULL,NULL);

      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
      gl3wInit();

      init();

      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
      {
        display();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPoolEvents();
      }

      glfwDestroyWindow(window);

      glfwTerminate();

    }
```

And yes, I know it's not complete code and init() as well as display() are yet undefined.

How to solve this and get it working ?

Comment: Please can you include the error as part of your question rather than via a link

Comment: Also include your code that's generating this error

Comment: Try including <GL/gl3w.h> first before the other header files

Comment: Then it gives that
``    In file included from B:\REPO\game\main.cpp:2:0: 
    b:\mingw\include\gl\glew.h:85:2: error: #error gl.h included before       glew.h 
    #error gl.h included before glew.h``

Comment: I've deleted `#include <GL/glew.h>` and it let it through, can't these 2 work together?

Comment: Well, i don't know whether that's the case, i was giving the advise shown here : https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w

Comment: As far as I can tell GLEW and GL3W achieve the same thing, why would you need to use both?

Comment: I thought I might need these two, I'm a begginer, thanks for clarifying :)